# When PersistentDict, when Folder?

Tags: python, zodb, repoze.bfg

When should I use a PersistentDict, and when should I use a Folder? What is the difference between them in terms of updates, internal structure, performance, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `PersistentMapping` is simply a implementation of the python `dict` type (via the standard library `UserDict` base class) adjusted for the Persistence semantics of the ZODB; it saves from having to set the `_p_changed` flag on the nearest class that inherits from `Persistent` every time you alter the `mapping`.

A `Folder` is a much richer type, implementing events, integration with the Zope web interface (ZMI), through-the-web arbitrary properties (attributes with type validation), management of Zope permissions, validation of sub-item ids, import/export, etc. Sub-items folders are stored as attributes on the object itself, with some metadata stored in a private dict on the instance.

Use a `Folder` when you need any of those extra services (delegation of permissions, id validation, etc), use a `PersistentMapping` otherwise. Performance wise looking up or storing items is not going to differ much; one is a straight python `dict` underneath, the other is the instance `__dict__` storing the items.

If you are looking for conflict avoidance, you should look into [BTrees](http://www.zodb.org/documentation/guide/modules.html#btrees-package), the `OOBTree` class is basically a persistent mapping where values are stored in persistent buckets, avoiding collisions in most cases, and providing conflict resolution for the rest.

If you want `Folder` semantics with `BTree` storage semantics, look at [Products.BTreeFolder2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.BTreeFolder2), and add-on that implements the `Folder` interfaces but stores sub-objects in a `OOBTree` instead of as attributes directly on the instances.

Answer (score 2):

A **PersistentDict** (now called a **PersistentMapping**) is a class that inherits from *UserDict.IterableUserDict* and *persistent.Persistent*.

*UserDict.IterableUserDict* is a built-in python class that simulates an iterable dictionary and *persistent.Persistent* is a Zope class that enables an instance of itself to be saved in the ZODB.

So a PersistentDict (or PersistentMapping) is basically a dictionary that can be stored as an object in the ZODB.

Normal dictionaries cannot be stored as separate objects in the ZODB. They have to be attributes of some class that inherits from *persistent.Persistent*.

PersistentDict stores its keys and values inside an actual dictionary (the *data* attribute).

A PersistentDict cannot be added through the ZMI and I think it's intended mostly for the special case where you want to store a dictionary directly in the zodb.

With a **Folder** I guess you mean the folder in *zope.container.folder*. 
A Folder stores it's children inside an OOBTree object, which is a container that can hold large amounts of objects.

When you want a container that contains instances of other content types, then you should rather go with a Folder.

A Folder has interfaces that a PersistentDict doesn't have and these interfaces may be required for certain adapters or other components to work. For example, the *ContainerModified* event will only fire when a Folder was modified, not a PersistentDict. There might be all kinds of gotchas like these if you use a PersistentDict as a general purpose Folder.

When it comes to performance, a dictionary will usually be faster until the keyspace becomes very large. Then the scales are tipped towards the OOBTree.

Comment: Can I concurrently modify different keys of a `PersistentDict` without `ConflictErrors`? Say I have `d={'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [5, 6, 7]}`, where those are `PersistentDict` and `PersistentList` instances. If one thread/process does `d['a'].append(5)`, and another does `del d['b'][2]`, and they both commit.. would that be a `ConflictError`? What about for a `Folder`? (I'm going to try this myself but have other stuff to do, first, so thought I might as well ask.)

Comment: Forget about any notion of a "folder" -- you need to compare PersistentDict to OOBTree (compare and apple to an apple, not to a fruit salad).  OOBTree should in many cases have superior conflict resolution, but IIRC for small mappings, you may have two keys in the same bucket, removing this advantage.  As the mapping gets bigger -- especially if you use a good strategy for the keys on insertions to be distributed evenly across buckets, I think you minimize chances of conflicts.

Comment: My take: just use BTrees (likely OOBTree for your example) for all but trivial or small mappings, and just realize that keys() returns an iterator that can be a moving target and acts more like iterkeys() -- this violates the way that dicts work in Python 2, and is closer in behavior to keys() in Python 3 (dictionary view versus iterator semantics aside).

Comment: @sdupton: ah a BTree, brilliant, think that is what i need to look into. thanks!